# Tax rate select missing from product price in commerce 8

Tags: 8, commerce

I installed `drupal commerce 8 rc2` and created a tax type of "European Union VAT".
When I create a new product, near the price field, I can't find the tax rate select.

How can I associate 10% or 22% vat rate to the price of product?

Comment: By writing a custom TaxRateResolver service. There is no UI for associating individual rates with products yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answere but my resolver never fire. i copy DefaultTaxRateResolver code.

into service.yml i wrote:
`multiple_price.italia_tax_rate_resolver:
    class: Drupal\multiple_price\Resolver\ItalianTaxRateResolver
    tags:
      - { name: commerce_tax.tax_rate_resolver, priority: -110 }`

into ItalianTaxRateResolver.php i put:

`class ItalianTaxRateResolver extends DefaultTaxRateResolver {
public function resolve(TaxZone $zone, OrderItemInterface $order_item, ProfileInterface $customer_profile) {`

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code that is not shown. We cannot say what is wrong in the code without seeing it.

Comment: Use the module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_tax

Answer (score 1):

Try these 3 references:

1) [Need to modify tax type based on user field in Drupal 8 Commerce 2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254857/need-to-modify-tax-type-based-on-user-field-in-drupal-8-commerce-2)

Here you can see an example of creating your own service in a custom module to interact with the default TaxOrderProcessor or writing a simple module to override the tax order processor service at all.

2) https://www.flocondetoile.fr/blog/apply-vat-rate-product-drupal-commerce-2

Here you can see how "to vary an applicable VAT rate according to a product, or a product type, we just need to implement a service that will declare the trade_tax.tax_rate_resolver tag with a priority at least higher than the default TaxResolver provided by Drupal Commerce."

3) https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/modifying-product-prices-drupal-commerce-2-drupal-8

Here you can see another example of application of "resolvers", the concept that do the work done bu Rules at Commerce 1, which is the key of the previous comment (link 2).

Ps: At the moment, poor documentation about this stuff, and no UI to manage this BASIC feature :-(

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens , I'm sorry, not very experienced user here :-) I just want to comment main question, but not possible due my lack of "points", that's why I use "answer" option instead of comment option. I just try to help adding some useful (?) info in a NOT SOLVED question.

About the UI: my opinion is free ;-) I'm not coder and I can think this BASIC feature should have an UI. But, worse, you were not be able to find any official documentation until yesterday, when I add this 3 link references in Drupal Commerce doc page :-p

Comment: OK, I see (and understand) your point (and "lack of points"). But hey, its perfectly OK to post such answers, and with links. What you should do however is further extend (edit) your answer, eg by adding a few lines (or relevant quotes) for each of the links you mentioned. After you did so, please drop me an extra comment and I'd be happy to "QA"-read it again (and possibly help you to further improve it somehow. OK? Good luck! PS: the 3rd link content does not include "tax" at all, so why should I look at that link (to answer the question here)?

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens , I've tried to improve my answer, as suggested. Could you remove you negative vote?
Regards

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, so I cannot "remove" that downvote. However, I'm adding "my" +1 now (much better after your edit ...).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pierre.Vriens , now I get unbanned at last! And I've could publish this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/258951/56420 (that's what I was trying to do for hours! :-) )
Thanks for your advices and your help ;-) See you!