# Drush migrate commands do not appear after fresh drupal 8 install using composer

Tags: drush, migrations, composer

I am trying to follow the [upgrade using drush](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-drush) tutorial but I cannot get the migrate commands to appear in drush. On a new Ubuntu 16 box I do:

```
#install a new drupal 8
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev drupal8 --stability dev --no-interaction
cd drupal8
composer install

#install drush
composer require drush/drush
cd /var/www/drupal8
wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.6.0/drush.phar
sudo mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush
```

I then go to the website and set it up. It creates the database etc. Everything seems OK. Then, I install the migration packages

```
cd /var/www/drupal8/drupal8
composer require drupal/migrate_upgrade
composer require drupal/migrate_plus
composer require drupal/migrate_tools
# Enable migration packages
drush en migrate migrate_drupal migrate_upgrade migrate_plus migrate_tools
drush cr
drush cc drush
```

At this point I have the migration packages installed and enabled:

```
% drush pml | grep Migration
  Migration             Migrate (migrate)                                  Enabled    8.5.1
  Migration             Migrate Advanced Example Setup                     Disabled   8.x-2.0-beta2
  Migration             Migrate Example Setup (migrate_example_setup)      Disabled   8.x-2.0-beta2
  Migration             Migrate Plus (migrate_plus)                        Enabled    8.x-2.0-beta2
  Migration             Migrate Tools (migrate_tools)                      Enabled    8.x-2.0-beta1
  Migration             Drupal Upgrade (migrate_upgrade)                   Enabled    8.x-2.0-beta1
```

and yet, `drush list` does not show any migrate commands:

```
%drush list
Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.1

Run `drush help [command]` to view command-specific help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.

 Available commands:
 _global:
   help                                       Display usage details for a command.
   list                                       List available commands.
   updatedb (updb)                            Apply any database updates required (as with running
                                              update.php).
   runserver (rs, serve)                      Runs PHP's built-in http server for development.
   browse                                     Display a link to a given path or open link in a
                                              browser.
   version                                    Show Drush version.
   generate (gen)                             Generate boilerplate code for
                                              modules/plugins/services etc.
   drupal:directory (dd)                      Return the filesystem path for modules/themes and
                                              other key folders.
   updatedb:status (updbst)                   List any pending database updates.
   twig:compile (twigc)                       Compile all Twig template(s).
 cache:
   cache:get (cg)                             Fetch a cached object and display it.
   cache:clear (cc)                           Clear a specific cache, or all Drupal caches.
   cache:set (cs)                             Cache an object expressed in JSON or var_export()
                                              format.
   cache:rebuild (cr, rebuild)                Rebuild a Drupal 8 site.
 config:
   config:pull (cpull)                        Export and transfer config from one environment to
                                              another.
   config:get (cget)                          Display a config value, or a whole configuration
                                              object.
   config:set (cset)                          Set config value directly. Does not perform a config
                                              import.
   config:edit (cedit)                        Open a config file in a text editor. Edits are
                                              imported after closing editor.
   config:delete (cdel)                       Delete a configuration key, or a whole object.
   config:status (cst)                        Display status of configuration (differences between
                                              the filesystem configuration and database
                                              configuration).
   config:export (cex)                        Export Drupal configuration to a directory.
   config:import (cim)                        Import config from a config directory.
 core:
   core:topic (topic)                         Read detailed documentation on a given topic.
   core:init (init)                           Enrich the bash startup file with bash aliases and a
                                              smart command prompt.
   core:edit (conf, config)                   Edit drushrc, site alias, and Drupal settings.php
                                              files.
   core:rsync (rsync)                         Rsync Drupal code or files to/from another server
                                              using ssh.
   core:status (status, st)                   An overview of the environment - Drush and Drupal.
   core:execute (exec, execute)               Execute a shell command. Usually used with a site
                                              alias.
   core:cron (cron)                           Run all cron hooks in all active modules for
                                              specified site.
   core:requirements (status-report, rq)      Information about things that may be wrong in your
                                              Drupal installation.
 entity:
   entity:updates (entup)                     Apply pending entity schema updates.
   entity:delete (edel)                       Delete content entities.
 image:
   image:flush (if)                           Flush all derived images for a given style.
   image:derive (id)                          Create an image derivative.
 locale:
   locale:check                               Checks for available translation updates.
   locale:update                              Imports the available translation updates.
 php:
   php:eval (eval, ev)                        Evaluate arbitrary php code after bootstrapping
                                              Drupal (if available).
   php:script (scr)                           Run php a script after a full Drupal bootstrap.
   php:cli (php, core:cli, core-cli)          Open an interactive shell on a Drupal site.
 pm:
   pm:security (sec)                          Check Drupal Composer packages for pending security
                                              updates.
   pm:enable (en)                             Enable one or more modules.
   pm:uninstall (pmu)                         Uninstall one or more modules and their dependent
                                              modules.
   pm:list (pml)                              Show a list of available extensions (modules and
                                              themes).
 queue:
   queue:run                                  Run a specific queue by name.
   queue:list                                 Returns a list of all defined queues.
   queue:delete                               Delete all items in a specific queue.
 role:
   role:create (rcrt)                         Create a new role.
   role:delete (rdel)                         Delete a new role.
   role:perm:add (rap, role-add-perm)         Grant specified permission(s) to a role.
   role:perm:remove (rmp, role-remove-perm)   Remove specified permission(s) from a role.
   role:list (rls)                            Display a list of all roles defined on the system.
 site:
   site:ssh (ssh)                             Connect to a Drupal site's server via SSH.
   site:install (si, sin)                     Install Drupal along with
                                              modules/themes/configuration/profile.
   site:set (use)                             Set a site alias that will persist for the current
                                              session.
   site:alias (sa)                            Show site alias details, or a list of available site
                                              aliases.
   site:alias-convert (sa-convert, sac)       Convert legacy site alias files to the new yml
                                              format.
 sql:
   sql:connect                                A string for connecting to the DB.
   sql:create                                 Create a database.
   sql:drop                                   Drop all tables in a given database.
   sql:cli (sqlc)                             Open a SQL command-line interface using Drupal's
                                              credentials.
   sql:query (sqlq)                           Execute a query against a database.
   sql:dump                                   Exports the Drupal DB as SQL using mysqldump or
                                              equivalent.
   sql:sync                                   Copy DB data from a source site to a target site.
                                              Transfers data via rsync.
   sql:sanitize (sqlsan)                      Sanitize the database by removing or obfuscating
                                              user data.
 state:
   state:get (sget)                           Display a state value.
   state:set (sset)                           Set a state value.
   state:delete (sdel)                        Delete a state entry.
 theme:
   theme:enable (then)                        Enable one or more themes.
   theme:uninstall (thun)                     Uninstall theme.
 user:
   user:login (uli)                           Display a one time login link for user ID 1, or
                                              another user.
   user:information (uinf)                    Print information about the specified user(s).
   user:block (ublk)                          Block the specified user(s).
   user:unblock (uublk)                       UnBlock the specified user(s).
   user:role:add (urol, user-add-role)        Add a role to the specified user accounts.
   user:role:remove (urrol, user-remove-role) Remove a role from the specified user accounts.
   user:create (ucrt)                         Create a user account.
   user:cancel (ucan)                         Cancel user account(s) with the specified name(s).
   user:password (upwd)                       Set the password for the user account with the
                                              specified name.
 views:
   views:dev (vd)                             Set several Views settings to more
                                              developer-oriented values.
   views:list (vl)                            Get a list of all views in the system.
   views:execute (vex)                        Execute a view and show a count of the results, or
                                              the rendered HTML.
   views:analyze (va)                         Get a list of all Views and analyze warnings.
   views:enable (ven)                         Enable the specified views.
   views:disable (vdis)                       Disable the specified views.
 watchdog:
   watchdog:show (wd-show, ws)                Show watchdog messages.
   watchdog:list (wd-list)                    Interactively filter the watchdog message listing.
   watchdog:delete (wd-del, wd-delete, wd)    Delete watchdog log records.
   watchdog:show-one (wd-one)                 Show one log record by ID.
```

Drush version is:

```
% drush --version
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
Drush Commandline Tool 9.2.1
```

I can see the packages are installed in the `web/modules/contrib` directory, where I find `migrate_tools/migrate_tools.drush.inc`. Drush should be finding this file and adding the commands in it. Why isn't it?

------------------- Update:

My website's `admin/modules/update` page told me that my migration modules were old (oddly, since I did `composer require..` just an hour ago). I updated them with:

```
composer require drupal/migrate_plus:4.0-beta3 drupal/migrate_tools:4.0-beta3 drupal/migrate_upgrade:3.0-rc4
drush cr
```

and now I do get some migrate commands, but not the `migrate-upgrade` command I need.

```
% drush list | grep migrate
 migrate:
   migrate:status (ms)                        List all migrations with current status.
   migrate:import (mim)                       Perform one or more migration processes.
   migrate:rollback (mr)                      Rollback one or more migrations.
   migrate:stop (mst)                         Stop an active migration operation.
   migrate:reset-status (mrs)                 Reset a active migration's status to idle.
   migrate:messages (mmsg)                    View any messages associated with a migration.
   migrate:fields-source (mfs)                List the fields available for mapping in a source.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer was that [migrate-upgrade still does not work with drush 9](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade/issues/2915726).  But, applying [the patch on that page](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-17/2915726-13.migrate_upgrade.Drush-9-port-of-commands.patch) does make it work.

The drush `migrate:upgrade` command appears!

Answer (score 3):

Your Migrate Tools and Migrate Upgrade tools have a version not suitable for Drupal 8.5.x. You can see at their web page. For example:

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade

> ```
> 8.x-3.x: This branch works with Drupal 8.2.x and above.
> 8.x-2.0: This release works only with Drupal 8.1.x. This release is no longer supported.
> 8.x-1.0: This release works only with Drupal 8.0.x. This release is no longer supported.
> ```

And https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools:

> ```
> 8.x-4.0-beta2+ - Compatible with Drupal 8.3.x and above and Drush 8/9, this is where primary development will be focused.
> 8.x-3.0-rc1 - Compatible with Drupal 8.2.x only, support for major/critical bug fixes only.
> 8.x-2.0 - Compatible with Drupal 8.1.x only, no longer supported.
> 8.x-1.0 - Compatible with Drupal 8.0.x only, no longer supported.
> ```

Then, you should update both:

```
composer require 'drupal/migrate_tools:^4.0'

composer require 'drupal/migrate_upgrade:^3.0'
```

And clear drush cache:

```
vendor/bin/drush cc drush
```

Not sure if a Drupal cache rebuit is needed (drush cr)

After it, you can see your migrate commands in the drush command list:

```
vendor/bin/drush list
```